# Installation Error of SQL Server 2012 during VS 2013 Express for Web Install

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Unable to successfully install SQL Server 2012 during install of VS 2013 Express for Web. The rest of the product installs correctly but I've never been able to install the Database part on my Lenovo G560 laptop. I've researched on the web but have been unable to find a solution.  I get the following error messages in the completion dialog:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client Package failed
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities Package failed
>   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDb Package failed

I would include the install log but there are space limitations on StackOverflow. Has anyone had a similar problem? How did you solve it?  Any help is appreciated.

W.W.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while installing Sql Server after VS 2013. I had install Sql Server first then install Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You may install this http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=116207

This is an updated version on the tools required to install SQL server stuff. Newer OSes need these updates to install SQL Server components.

Hope this helps.